# Git how to find what my branch have done after merged into another branch

Tags: git

I've checkout branch A from master ,after doing some commits branch A have merged into master, now how I can see what I've done in branch A intuitively not by check commit one by one ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the diff between two commits. If the merge of branch `A` into `master` created a merge commit (`MC`), then you simply compare the merge commit with it's first parent:

`git diff MC~1 MC`

Oftentimes you may wish to start by viewing just what files changed:

`git diff MC~1 MC --name-only`

If you don't have a merge commit because the merge used fast-forward, then you can't figure out what you want without also knowing what commit `A` branched off of. Maybe you can figure that out by the author and dates of the commits. Just substitute `MC` above with the parent of the first commit ID:

`git diff <first-commit-ID-on-A>~1 A`

**Side Note:** When viewing the first parent, the following are all equivalent:

```
X~1
X^
X^1
```

However, if `A` created a backwards merge commit by first merging in `master` and then merging `A` into `master` with fast-forward, from `master`'s point of view you'd need to compare the second parent:

`git diff X^2 X`

Note that merging the target branch into the source branch and then merging back into the target with fast forward is frowned upon and should generally be avoided.